# Coldfusion 9 Hotfixes

Tags: coldfusion, updates, coldfusion-9, hotfix

I am trying to get a server running CF9 up-to-date by applying all of the available hotfixes listed here:

http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/hot-fixes-coldfusion-9.html

However, I do not know which hotfixes have been applied.  The version number being reported by the CFIDE is "9,0,1,274733".

Can I just start at the bottom (oldest first) and just apply all of the hotfixes one by one until they are all accounted for?

Answer (score 2):

You are on ColdFusion 9.01.

ColdFusion 9.0.1: Cumulative hot fix 4  chf4_cf901  03/08/2013

This this the most recent **Cumulative hot fix**. The also brings in Java 7 support. Note that Java 6, the version shipped with CF 9.x, has been "End of Lifed".

Additional security patches can be found on the Adobe site

http://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/coldfusion.html

http://helpx.adobe.com/security.html#coldfusion